# Android multiple clickable span is not working for textview

Tags: java, android

Here is my textview

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/termsTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            />
```

Here is a code for clickable span

```
 termsTv=findViewById(R.id.termsTv);
            String word = getResources().getString(R.string.eql_terms);
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(word);
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://eql.app/terms-and-conditions.php"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            };

            ClickableSpan clickableSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://eql.app/privacy-policy.php"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            };
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 75, 87, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 81, 109, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            termsTv.setText(ss);
            termsTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I am implementing multiple clickable span for my textview to view terms and privacy policy. When I set only one span it's working, but when set two clickable span for my textview click it is not working. I tried debugging; Debug is not executing inside the clickablespan onclick method. I don't know what will be the exact issue.

Comment: I tested your code. But there was no problem. Can you email me the code so I can test more accurately

Comment: @JavadDehban: readers cannot stop you, but in general we don't want code emailed - we want it shown here. When volunteer support is rendered in private, that assistance usually does not get recorded on the public question, and future readers do not get to learn from the solution.

Comment: @halfer yes, of course. I'm just helping.